# how to return newest object from the FIFO Queue without removing it

Tags: c#

`Peek` Returns the object at the beginning of the Queue without removing it.

What if I want to do the same thing with the "last object in the queue". I.e. the "newest" one (the one was just inserted).

I've tried `queue.Reverse().Peek()` but this doesn't compile.

Comment: You should probably using a Stack, if that indeed is your requirement.

Comment: @JKarthik i need to add objects, remove objects using FIFO, iterate objects from newest to oldest and "peek" newest object. for iteration i'm using `queue.Reverse()`

Comment: you can just use queue.last()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660139/reverse-a-queue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
queue.Last()
```

`queue.Reverse().Peek()` does not work because `Reverse()` returns an instance of `IEnumerable<T>`, which does not define a `Peek()` method.

Comment: then `fastOrders.First()` is the same as `Peek`? what's the difference between `First` and `Peek`?

Comment: `Peek()` has been around since .NET 2.0, while Linq (and `First()`) is available from .NET 3.5

Comment: Be aware that .Last() is an O(N) operation for Queues.

Comment: @MatthewWatson are you talking about general queies or about microsoft queue? As `Reverse` is O(1) for Microsoft queue, I assume that `Last` is also O(1)